# How to receive the android.nfc.action.TAG_LOST intent to detect tag removal?

Tags: android, android-intent, tags, nfc

According to the [AOSP source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+blame/155b0ee0498cf863091f3f83a752eaaedf1257f8/core/java/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.java#78), `NfcAdapter` defines a constant `ACTION_TAG_LEFT_FIELD` with a string value of `"android.nfc.action.TAG_LOST"`.

The Javadoc in the file states:

> Broadcast to only the activity that handles ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED

Blame shows that this declaration got added in 2010 during the initial NFC implementation, thus any NFC-capable version of Android should have it (save for builds that specifically removed it).

I have an activity that listens to any of `ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED`, `ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED` and `ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED`. I've tried to get it to listen to `ACTION_TAG_LEFT_FIELD` both by declaring it in the manifest and by registering a BroadcastReceiver, but the activity never receives the intent. I've tried both an NDEF-formatted tag and a generic tag (one triggers `ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED`, the other triggers `ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED`), and with two different devices running different versions of Android.

If it matters: the app never does an explicit `connect()` operation to read from the tag but takes all tag data from the Intent extras.

Has anyone successfully received the `android.nfc.action.TAG_LOST` broadcast? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This field is indeed declared in the `NfcAdapter` API:

```
/**
 * Broadcast to only the activity that handles ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED
 * @hide
 */
public static final String ACTION_TAG_LEFT_FIELD = "android.nfc.action.TAG_LOST";
```

However, notice that its declared as hidden (`@hide`), so it is not part of any public API, and consequently, there is no documented way of using this.

In fact, eventhough this has been defined in the `NfcAdapter` API class, it isn't used by Android. The Android NFC service does not even try to send this intent. Consequently, there is no way for your app to receive it.